# Counting term frequency in list of strings in pd dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, nlp, tf-idf

I have a dataframe and one column contains the lemmatized words of a paragraph. I wish to count the frequency of each word within the whole dataframe, not just within the record. There are over 40,000 records so the computation has to be quick and not reach the limit of my RAM.

For example, this basic input:

```
ID                             lemm
 1                ['test','health']
 2  ['complete','health','science']
```

would have this desired output:
'complete':1
'health':2
'science':1
'test':1

This is my current code:

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = Counter()
for entry in df.lemm:
  for word in entry:
    cnt[word]+=1
cnt
```

Which works when I manually enter a list of a list of strings (ex/[['completing', 'dog', 'cat'], ['completing','degree','health','health']]), but not when it iterates through the df.

I have also tried this:

```
top_N=20
word_dist = nltk.FreqDist(df_main.stem)
print('All frequences')
print('='*60)
rslt=pd.DataFrame(word_dist.most_common(top_N),columns=['Word','Frequency'])
print(rslt)
```

to return the top 20 terms, but the output lists the frequencies of terms within the entry, not the entire dataframe.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can try `explode` if you have Pandas 0.25+:

```
df.Text.explode().value_counts()
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can the counter line to:
cnt = Counter(word for entry in df.lemm for word in entry)

Refer to: [How to find the lemmas and frequency count of each word in list of sentences in a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52860350/how-to-find-the-lemmas-and-frequency-count-of-each-word-in-list-of-sentences-in)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your column names and input data:

```
 data = {
    "ID": [1, 2],
    "lemm": [['test', 'health'], ['complete', 'health', 'science']]
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
freq = df.explode("lemm").groupby(["lemm"]).count().rename(columns={"ID" : "Frecuency"})
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import Counter
cnt = df.apply(lambda x:Counter(x['lemm']),axis=1).sum()
```

Will do it for you. That will make `cnt` a Counter object so you can do most common on it or anything else counter offers.